# tkinter event binding to button

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, pandas, ipython

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

def callback():
   print "click!"

b = Button(master, text="OK", command=callback)
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

Right now running this in iPython prints "click!" to the console. If I would like result of a script or function to appear in the GUI box, under the button how can I achieve this? Does the size of the box need to be allocated in advanced?

**Edit:** The function I want to call is actually more complicated than callback above. When I run the following code, instead of printing clusOne.head() it prints

```
<function centroid at 0x2cf3410>
```

to the output box. I would like to be able to print the lines of data resulting from this function rather than the pointer address.

```
master = Tk()


# The output box prints an address (pointer) as a result of running this function. 
#I would like to see the output in the box.

df=pd.read_csv('8162013.csv')
df=df.set_index('date1')

# Initialize the centroid.
cen1=df.mean()
v=ny.random.randn()+10
cen2=df.mean()-v
train=df[0:1615]


def centroid(train,cen1,cen2):

  for i in range(0,3):

    # Sum of squares. Results in a series containing 'date' and 'num' 
    sorted1=((train-cen1)**2).sum(1)
    sorted2=((train-cen2)**2).sum(1)

    # This makes a list of the cluster1 and cluster2
     a=[train.ix[i] for i in train.index if sorted1[i]<sorted2[i]]
     b=[train.ix[i] for i in train.index if sorted1[i]>=sorted2[i]]

     # Back to a dataframe...
    clusOne=pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['ES','US','GC'])
    clusTwo=pd.DataFrame(b,columns=['ES','US','GC'])

 # Update the centroid.
    cen1=clusOne.mean()
    cen2=clusTwo.mean()

     print clusOne.head()
     print "I'm computing your centroid."




def callback():
   listbox.insert(END, centroid)

  b = Button(master, text="Cluster", command=callback)
  listbox = Listbox(master)
   b.pack()
   listbox.pack()

   mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a tkinter list box and add text to it every time some one presses the button:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

def callback():
   listbox.insert(END, "Click!")

b = Button(master, text="OK", command=callback)
listbox = Listbox(master)
b.pack()
listbox.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, the actual function I need to see results of doesn't show it in the output box. Thoughts?

Comment: When you say output box, do you mean the listbox? I'm pretty sure your problem is that you need to **call** your `centroid` rather than just referencing it (don't forget to give it it's parameters).

Comment: Supposing that the function didn't have parameters, I assume you mean it should be command=callback()? (i.e., parenthesis)  Although looking at the 'Using Functions' section, in this example, they don't pass callback() to command in the button function.

Comment: I meant calling the `centroid` function in the `callback` function rather than just referencing it. Also, make your `centroid` function return what you want to be put into the listbox.